# smtp.Dial("ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM:25") connection error; but putty connections work

Tags: go, smtp

When using Go and [`smtp.Dial`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#Dial),
or even `net.Dial`,
I get the error:

> dial tcp 64.233.169.27:25: ConnectEx tcp: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond.

From this code:

```
mxClient, err := smtp.Dial("ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM:25")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

What I don't understand is that I can connect and send commands (`HELO`, etc) using putty on port 25 without TLS.
If it's a limitation of the package not able to make the connection,
is there a recommended way to make a raw socket connection like putty in Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any error on my machine.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/smtp"
)

func main() {
        mxClient, err := smtp.Dial("ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM:25")
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%#v", mxClient)
}
```

gives

```
&smtp.Client{Text:(*textproto.Conn)(0xc208074000), conn:(*net.TCPConn)(0xc20802c018), tls:false, serverName:"ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM", ext:map[string]string(nil), auth:[]string(nil), localName:"localhost", didHello:false, helloError:error(nil)}
```

Comment: Ugh. It works on my other computer fine. Both running windows 10 preview so Im going to reinstall golang. Already tried reinstalling the packages before. THank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP might be blocking port 25. I have to use port 587 to googles smtp server to connect.

Comment: If that was the case then it would be expected that anything making port 25 connections would be blocked but the OP says putty works fine.

Comment: Yes, sorry you are correct. I'm experiencing a weird error myself now. When I use the code in aamir's answer I can't connect to "ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM" even when I change the port to 587. When I change the code to smtp.Dial("smtp.gmail.com:587") it works fine. But the thing is I telnet to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM on 587 and it works fine. Its strange I can connect to "aspmx....com" using telnet but not Go?